# How to display specific Log data to ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, I have created a basic React App. How is it possible to display data to a specific `form log`?

Current App Behaviour, they are showing all `forms log preview`.

[image]

**Code snippet: (DEMO)** and this is the code I'm writing

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-parm-4bdhc5

**Output:**
[image]

When I click the `log Preview` button, I want to see specific `form log preview` data.

[image]

How to do it? What should I change in my code?

Could anyone please help me with it? Thanks

Comment: you want to get that data that just clicked right?

Comment: yes [@MirzaIrtiza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17743636/mirza-irtiza)